# Provider in lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I created a new Angular project with a lazy loaded module (LazyModuleModule).

Stackblitz: [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fthkkc)

This module is lazy loaded in the routing module:

```
   loadChildren: () => import('../app/lazy-module/lazy-module.module').then(m => m.LazyModuleModule)
```

The lazy module itself has no components or any directives. It only imports another eagerly loaded module "EagerModule" with a single component (ShowComponent).

In this component I want to inject a service (TestService) that derives from an abstract Service "TestAbstractService".

I now provided the TestServiceAbstract in the EagerModule:

```
{provide: TestServiceAbstract, useClass: TestService}
```

But when compiling the project I get an errorMessage: "Can't resolve all parameters for ShowComponent".

I really do not see any reason why this approach should not work. If I provide the TestService directly in the app.module everything works, but this is strange to me.

**Hint:** To see the error message in stackblitz, you need to open the console and click on the "something magic happen"-text. This routes to the component with the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The import for '**TestServiceAbstract**' is not done in **ShowComponent**. You have imported '**TestService**' instead of '**TestServiceAbstract**' in **ShowComponent**.

Add the proper import for TestServiceAbstract which you are injecting in the constructor:

```
import { TestServiceAbstract } from '../../abstract.test.service';
```

Please replace the show.component.ts with below code. This should work:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestServiceAbstract } from '../../abstract.test.service';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-show',
   templateUrl: './show.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./show.component.css']
})
export class ShowComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(public testService: TestServiceAbstract) { }

   ngOnInit() {
     alert(this.testService.getNumber())
   }
}
```

[Show component with alert message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vb7fD.png)